# SQL: How can I proper case all words in a string unless they're <= 3 chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, uppercase

I'm looking for  SQL function that will look through a string and proper case each word unless it's <= 3 characters... in which case it needs to be all caps

For example:

> 2021 CHEVROLET Silverado Ltz

would become

> 2021 Chevrolet Silverado LTZ

---

> 2020 HONDA CIVIC LX SEDAN

would be come

> 2020 Honda Civic LX Sedan

I've written a function that will look at the entirety of a string and its length, I'm just not sure how to look at each item once delimited by a space. Here's the function as I have it now.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ucwords] (@InputString VARCHAR(4000), @wordsLongerThan INT = -1 )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
IF @InputString IS NULL
    RETURN NULL;

IF (@wordsLongerThan <> -1 AND LEN(@InputString) < @wordsLongerThan)
    return @InputString;

DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 2
SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString,1,1)))

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    IF @Char IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&','''','(')
    IF @Index + 1 <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    IF @Char != ''''
    OR
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)) != 'S'
    SET @OutputString =
    STUFF(@OutputString, @Index + 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)))
END
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN ISNULL(@OutputString,'')
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Three letter words not supposed to be in upper case: Kia, Vaz, De (Lorean), De (Tomaso) etc

Comment: 1) SQL Server 2016 - 2) Part of Kia compliance is that their name appears in all caps for marketing purposes... dumb I know - but still. Also, Delorean is 1 word and Vaz it techinicall avtovaz

Comment: CLR function is much easier than doing in SQL.

Comment: What about Nissan Pao? Kia Rio? Making some assumptions you might regret but I guess you can always clean up by searching for 3 letter (or fewer) words after.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using SQL Server 2016, try the following:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ucwords ( 
    @Sentence varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varchar(4000)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Cased varchar(4000) = '';  --<-- initializing to an empty string is important.

    SELECT
        @Cased = @Cased + ' ' + CASE 
            WHEN LEN ( Word ) <= 3 THEN UPPER ( Word )
            ELSE UPPER ( LEFT ( Word, 1 ) ) + LOWER ( RIGHT ( Word, LEN ( Word ) - 1 ) )
        END
    FROM ( 
        
        SELECT value AS Word FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @Sentence, ' ' )

    ) AS Words;

    RETURN LTRIM ( @Cased );

END
GO
```

Then try:

```
SELECT dbo.ucwords ( '2020 HONDA CIVIC LX SEDAN' ) AS [ucwords];
```

Returns

```
+---------------------------+
|          ucwords          |
+---------------------------+
| 2020 Honda Civic LX Sedan |
+---------------------------+
```

Also try:

```
SELECT dbo.ucwords ( '2021 CHEVROLET Silverado Ltz' ) AS [ucwords];
```

Returns

```
+------------------------------+
|           ucwords            |
+------------------------------+
| 2021 Chevrolet Silverado LTZ |
+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

At DB Compat 130 and later you can use STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG in your function to split apart the sentences, use LEN to see if it is more than 3 chars and set the case accordingly:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ucwords] (@InputString VARCHAR(4000), @wordsLongerThan INT = -1 )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
IF @InputString IS NULL
    RETURN NULL;

IF (@wordsLongerThan <> -1 AND LEN(@InputString) < @wordsLongerThan)
    return @InputString;

DECLARE @StringAsTable TABLE (
    RowNum INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    StringVal VARCHAR(4000)
)
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255)

INSERT @StringAsTable(StringVal)
SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InputString, ' ')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';

UPDATE @StringAsTable
SET StringVal = UPPER(StringVal)
WHERE LEN(StringVal) <= 3;

UPDATE @StringAsTable
SET StringVal = UPPER(LEFT(StringVal, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(StringVal, 2, LEN(StringVal)))
WHERE LEN(StringVal) > 3;

SELECT @OutputString = STRING_AGG(StringVal, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RowNum ASC)
FROM @StringAsTable ;

RETURN ISNULL(@OutputString, '');
END
```

Comment: The ```UPDATES``` could probably be combined in a ```CASE``` statement as well